# Div tag background colours CSS HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm having difficulties with DIV tags again. I have managed to make it so that the users screen into 3 columns. But I'm now trying to add an individual background to each div. But the `style="background:blue;"` or `style="background-color:blue;"` don't seem to work.

Any help would be appreciated :)

http://prntscr.com/2kde62 <-- what I wanted it to look like(I used an Image for the background)

http://prntscr.com/2kdedk <-- what it look like even with the style="background:blue;"

Code Below:

```
<div id='leftDiv' style="float:left; margin:0; width:33%;" align="center">

       <img style="position:absolute; top:160; left:170;" onclick="addKittens()" src="http://imgur.com/3mj6PL5.jpg" width="192" height="192">
</div>

<div id='middleDiv' style="float:left; margin:0; width:33%;" align="left">

    <img style="position:absolute; top:200; left:650;" onclick='crazyLadyAdd()' src="http://imgur.com/7sucpdi.jpg" width="96" height="96"> <!-- Crazy Cat Lady image --> 
    <img style="position:absolute; top:300; left:650;" onclick='milkFactoryAdd()' src="http://imgur.com/Q9y4xBJ.png" width="96" height="96"> <!-- Milk Factory image --> 
</div>

<div id='rightDiv' style="float:left; margin:0; width:33%; background:blue;" align="center">
    <p style="position:absolute; left:1200; color:red; font-size:20;"> PLACEHOLDER </p>  
</div>
```

Comment: Please show CSS classes

Comment: Have you tried `background-color: blue !important;`? It might be a CSS Specificity issue.

Comment: You're sure the blue background isn't hidden behind the red of the paragraph?

Comment: @Robuust I havent got a CSS, Im just adding the style to the <div> tags.

Comment: @HashemQolami Just tried that with no avail.

Comment: @DavidThomas I doubt it because it just tried it with all of the other Div's, still didnt work :s

Comment: So apply `background-color: transparent;` to the paragraph, and I think it *should* work.

Comment: @DavidThomas I just done that. Still nothing.

Comment: In which case you should provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), at [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), or similar demo-site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that all your div have no **height** attribute. Usually, the div wraps its children blocks, i.e. the img in your situation. However, you have set the img `position:absolute`, so the parent div cannot get height correctly.

Comment: Nice catch (I'd overlooked the `float`).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the:

```
{background-color:#b0c4de;}
```

to the CSS of that layout? Make your 'rightDiv' in CSS# and you can place in the code above, it should load.

Comment: Why would that help? The `style` attribute is already far more specific than the CSS declared elsewhere (unless there's an `!important` set somewhere else).

Comment: It is why I asked had it not been tried, not that I was able to solve world issues. 'tried', David.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
Overflow:hidden
```

to all three columns or if the height is fixed, add

```
height:xyzpx
```

to all three div's.

Comment: I just added this, Still nothing :s

Comment: You have set "position:absolute;" to all of your images, that's why the wrapper div is not showing the bg color, can u remove the position from your images?

Comment: http://prntscr.com/2kdiuz I don't know what happened. But it broke without absolute position.

Comment: How do I make the background extend to the bottom of the screen?

Comment: have u set width:100%; to your main wrapper? 
also You have to set height in pixcel to your all three div's. if its dynamic use js generated height which will pass document height to you.

Comment: add css's reset code to your css, check this link http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working sample for your case. The position absolute on the images are messing it up.

```
<div id='leftDiv' style="float:left;margin:0; width:33%;background:yellow   ;" align="center">

       <img onclick="addKittens()" src="http://imgur.com/3mj6PL5.jpg" width="192" height="192">
</div>

<div id='middleDiv' style="float:left;margin:0; width:33%;background:red;" align="left">

    <img style="width:96;height:96;margin-top:200px" onclick='crazyLadyAdd()' src="http://imgur.com/7sucpdi.jpg" /> <!-- Crazy Cat Lady image --> 
    <img onclick='milkFactoryAdd()' src="http://imgur.com/Q9y4xBJ.png" width="96" height="96" /> <!-- Milk Factory image --> 
</div>

<div id='rightDiv' style="float:left; margin:0; width:33%; background:blue;" align="center">
    <p style="color:red; font-size:20;"> PLACEHOLDER </p>  
</div>
```

You should be able to figure out the height of the images yourself. But stop using **absolute** on all elements. Adding a **height** to the divs can also fix your issue.

Comment: This did work thank you. Now I just gotta learn how to move things without absolute position :s

Comment: Margin, padding and other CSS elements.

And maybe you better use a stylesheet instead of inline css only.

Answer (score 0):

The div-boxes have no height due to placing the images absolute. Give them 100% height and you can style them or place the images centered and not absolute.